# Maker checker in TFS (Team Foundation server)

Tags: .net, tfs

Is there any option in TFS that enables a lead to review to code before it is getting checked in by the developer? Like a maker checker process

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Code Review before checking in to TFS 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605446/code-review-before-checking-in-to-tfs-2013)

Comment: We are using VS 2010 with TFS 2013. Seems like the Code review is there only from VS2012. Is there any thing for VS2010?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [check-in policy](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c476b708-77a8-4065-b9d0-919ab688f078) which allows you to enforce Code Reviews at checkin time. Please notice this policy only works for VS 2013 right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [this](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9ef817b4-2c6d-4213-8b08-5be48f9d91b9). Seems like they support 2010.

[image]