# Code review in TFS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfs-2015

I want to review the code before it is checked in to TFS 2015. But I am not getting "Request Review" under the "Actions" tab. What should I do to get that option?

I'm using TFS 2015 with Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 2):

There has been a great tutorial about the  [built-in code review capabilities in TFS 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs). You could just follow the detail steps. To ask for a code review, make sure you have shared your code in TFVC.

As for missing **Request Review** feature under the in progress work tab. Please double check if you are working on VS2012 **Professional**.

> Code review is a feature that's currently available in **Premium** or
>   **Ultimate** with VS2012.

Either to use Premium or Ultimate with VS2012 or directly use VS2015 and above. More info please take a look at the comments from *Jazaret* and *Cocowalla* in this question: [Code Review before checking in to TFS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26605446/code-review-before-checking-in-to-tfs-2013)